# Can anyone identify this connector? Havent got a plug

Tags: identification

Trying to find a plug for the light in a display cabinet I just bought but have never seen this type of connector.  Wasn't sure if anyone on here could help.[image: Pic 1]

[image: Pic 2]

[image: Pic 3]

Comment: That's the sort of thing you're better off lopping off and replacing with something standard.

Comment: What you have *is* a plug (it has pins). You are looking for the socket. As pointed out above, replace it with some standard connector available in your area. Make sure that the plugs go on the lights and the sockets on the mains leads.

Comment: what is at the other end of the cable?

Answer (score 3):

Looks generally similar to the Ikea ANSLUTA connectors used for stringing under-cabinet lights together.

[image]

Comment: But aren’t these connectors and this cable designed for 12V DC?

Comment: @user2233709 Maybe? I have similar looking ones that are rated 125VAC though under my office cabinets. From Ikea.

Comment: Super old but for clarity no, these are mains voltage rated and supply power to the transformers/drivers that in turn power the lights.